# Can't use LocBaml with WPF .Net 5.0 project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, .net-5, locbaml

I have a very simple WPF project (.Net 5.0) that I'm trying to localize.

I downloaded the locbaml tool project as part of the wpf samples and I built it in Visual Studio 2019 - Release mode. This built OK.

I've run "MSBuild" to add the UID's (msbuild /t:updateid WPFLocalizationWithXAML.csproj) to my project. This worked ok and added the UID's.

My problem is that I can't parse "WPFLocalizationWithXAML.resources.dll" with "LocBaml.exe". I've copied "LocBaml.exe" (as built above) and "WPFLocalizationWithXAML.exe" into the "\en-us" folder so that they sit with "WPFLocalizationWithXAML.resources.dll". I then ran the following command (locbaml /parse WPFLocalizationWithXAML.resources.dll /out:trans.csv) but this always results in the following error and a trans.cvs file wth garbage in it:

> "Microsoft (R) Baml Localization Utility 1.0.0.0 Could not load file
> or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified"

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LocBAML tool still uses .NET Framework 4.7.2 as you can see [in its project file](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Tools/LocBaml/LocBaml.csproj). It is not yet ported to .NET Core and .NET 5 and **incompatible** to them. There is an open issue on GitHub.

- [Can't use LocBaml with WPF .NetCore 3.1 project in Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22251/cant-use-locbaml-with-wpf-netcore-31-project-in-vi.html)
- [Port LocBaml WPF application localization tool to .NET core](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/issues/85) (Closed)
- [Port LocBaml WPF application localization tool to .NET core](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1480)

Remember that the LocBAML tool was never intended to be used in production, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-localize-an-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

> The LocBaml tool is **not a production-ready application**. It is presented as a sample that uses some of the localization APIs and illustrates how you might write a localization tool.

As an alternative, you could do localization using resource files (`.resx`), see for example:

- [Localizing a WPF app running on .NET Core 3 in 2020](https://tomaskohl.com/code/2020-06-24/localizing-wpf-app-on-net-core/)
- [Localization in WPF using .resx files for different languages.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bfb8d13-3a86-4c10-a632-bb20c99d0535/localization-in-wpf-using-resx-files-for-different-languages?forum=wpf)
- [Tutorialspoint -WPF - Localization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_localization.htm)